# ASP.NET dynamic data listviewbinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am having trouble with binding some data to a listview in ASP.NET.
I am making a database mangement page where I can select a table from a database in a combobox.
When you select the table, a listview appears with all the data of that table. Now I want to use databinding and i don't really know how to handle this.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvData" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
       <table class="tableresults">
        <thead>
           <tr class="odd">
               <th>
                  <%# Eval('COLUMNTITLE') %>
               </th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">
             <%# Eval('PROPERTY') %>
          </th>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

So basically I need some kind of loop in the layouttemplate and itemtemplate that loops over the 'columntitles' and 'values' of the data I get from the database.
Can I achieve this with databinding?

So I just use code like this:

```
lvData.DataSource = getData();
lvData.DataBind();
```

thx

Comment: are you really using MVC? this doenst look like MVC.

Comment: Yes, I simplified some code to ask my question, I am working with views, but I don't think this is relevant to my question, I see if I can untag the aps.net-mvc tag.

Answer (score 0):

try use ItemDataBound event will fired after databind for each row of your data, you can manage and edit your content as you want

```
protected void dlList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
             .....
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
             ........

}
```

Regards